# jQuery to work out number of minutes between tweets

Tags: jquery, twitter

I am trying to work out how to calculate the number of minutes between two separate tweets and use it within jQuery code. Does anyone who has any knowledge of the Twitter API know how to do this?

Comment: Without more information about your specific implementation, there isn't any real way to answer your question for you other than writing the widget you describe.  :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the Twitter-API you get the `created_at` field (tried JSON) something like this `Wed, 20 Apr 2011 09:36:39 +0000`.

With Javascript you can put that in a `Date` Object:

`foo = new Date('Wed, 20 Apr 2011 09:36:39 +0000')`

You can get the UNIX Timestamp with `foo.getTime()` in milliseconds `1303292199000`

With some simple math you can now calculate the time between two tweets...

Simple...for that part you don't need jQuery.